# Data structure to use for binary search on large data sets

Tags: java

I am trying to implement binary search into my application.
I am creating a method to go through the user's contact list, add the numbers to an array, sort it and then use a binary search to locate numbers etc.

But I was thinking what kind of array should I just use ArrayList, then sort it and then implement a binary search.
Or is there a way to store the data? like sets, or maps etc?

Scenario - I'll be getting the users contacts from their phone. Every number, of course, needs to be stored in an array or list (whichever is better).
Then sort that array. 
Now I want to search for a number using a Binary search. Since a user can have a large contact set, I thought this would be a good method

Comment: If you have to run binary search, then you need a collection that supports ordering. So your options are pretty much limited to `List` types.

Comment: Why do you need binary search? Please give example of searches you want to execute.

Comment: The answer depends on which operations you want to run and what you want to optimize on (time complexity, space complexity). So please explain which queries you want to run, how would you add items and what you optimize for. Also exactly how large is a "large data set".

Comment: I have edited my description. Hope this helps!

Comment: If you simply want to search contact by number, `HashMap` of numbers to contacts would be a better choice from time complexity point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three basic options:

- Sorted list or array + binary search.
- Tree-based structure like `TreeMap`.
- Hash-based structure like `HashMap`.

The question is why you need binary search. If you simply want to look up contact info by number, then a `HashMap` would probably be a better choice from time complexity perspective.

Binary search would make sense if you have some order in keys and are interested in something like range queries. But even in this case a tree-based structure like `TreeMap` would be a better choice. Not so much for the time complexity (that will be pretty much the same) but more from the interface point of view.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a HashMap, since it has O(1) look-up vs O(log n) look-up in a sorted array.

So if your main concern is look-up (search), go for Hash.

Comment: The OP wants a binary search.

Comment: @lexicore No, the emphasis wasn't on the 'binary search'.

Comment: "binary search" was mentioned 3x in the post. Time complexity: zero times.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp the <H1> reads: Data structure to use for large data sets

Comment: _I am trying to implement binary search into my application._ I think that's pretty clear. But I guess we need to wait for OP to clarify.

Comment: I have edited my description. Hope this helps! but yes, I want to implement a binary search as Johnny said. My fault, I might not of been clear enough in my initial desc